# Can refresh multiple table when Incremental refresh is set up?

Tags: tableau-api

I'm new to tableau.

I set up incremental refresh on my datasource.

But I could only choose one table to refresh like below image.

[image]

Question

- Can I refresh multiple table with incremental refresh?
- Is the only way to refresh all table in datasource is full refresh?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally know that it is impossible. (version 2020.3)
if you want it, you should use join to connect tables, not relationship.